# Hide Child Elements related parent element only in angular 2

Tags: angular, hide, parent-child

> I am new in angular 2. If I click any "button", that next span only
>   closed.

```
<div class="parent">
<button>Click</button>
  <span>Element One</span>
</div>
<div class="parent">
<button>Click</button>
  <span>Element Two</span>
</div>
<div class="parent">
<button>Click</button>
  <span>Element Three</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l2jxxr)**

HTML :

```
<div class="parent1">
<button (click)="hide('parent1')">Click</button>
  <span #elOne>Element One</span>
</div>
<div class="parent2">
<button (click)="hide('parent2')">Click</button>
  <span #elTwo>Element Two</span>
</div>
<div class="parent3">
<button (click)="hide('parent3')">Click</button>
  <span #elThree>Element Three</span>
</div>
```

ts:

```
export class AppComponent  {

   hide(parentClass){
      let span = document.querySelector("." + parentClass + ' span');
      span.style.visibility = 'hidden'
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Bougarfaoui El houcine, Thanks for the replay..., For example here " parent " classes are generated dynamically, Countless then what we can do? please help me....